# How to use sub() to match pattern over multiple lines?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, substitution

I am using the `sub()` function to replace `===Something here===` with `<h2>Something here</h2>`.

The following is working:

```
line = sub(r"(===)([a-zA-Z\s]*)(===)", r"<h2>\2</h2>", line)
```

Where the original content is:

```
===Something here===
```

However it is not working when the original content is:

```
===
Something here
===
```

I have tried things like:

```
line = sub(r"(===\n)([a-zA-Z\s]*)(===)", r"<h2>\2</h2>", line)
```

(the only change being the addition of the `\n` in the first group)

but I think that enforces that the pattern contain a new line, rather than being an optional part of the pattern.

How do I extend the current pattern so that it is flexible enough to recognise instances where a new line may be present?

**Edit:**

I have tried the suggestion below (at time of writing) and they are not working.  The only reason I can think of is because there are possibly other characters in the line.

The following images are screenshots of the original text file (opened in SciTE editor with 'End of Line' and 'Whitespace' set to show) that is being read with:

```
original_text_file = open('file.txt', 'U')
```

Single Line Instance:

[image]

Multiline Instance:

[image]

I don't know if other considerations need to be made for these characters?

**Edit Two:**

Results from testing another solution below (this did not perform substitution on multiline instance):

**python code:**

```
from re import *

def test_function(text_file):
    file_object = open(text_file+'.txt', 'U')
    for line in file_object:
        line = sub(r"\n?(===)\n?([a-zA-Z\s]*?)\n?(===)\n?\n?", r"<h2>\2</h2>", line)
        print line

test_function('my_file')
```

**my_file.txt:**

```
===Something here===

Lorem ipsum lala.  

===
Something here
===

Loreum ipsum lala.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of a regular expression is appropriate here. Your expression was close to being what you needed. After a `\n` you needed `?` which matches `0` or `1` occurences of the character before it, in this case 0 or 1 `\n`'s. This had to be placed in several locations to cope with possible newlines. You also had to make the `\s` in your target capture group not consume the optional `\n` or else you would end up with a `\n` in the output.

```
import re
pat = r'\n?(===)\n?([a-zA-Z\s]*?)\n?(===)\n?\n?'
rep = r'<h2>\2</h2>'

print(repr(re.sub(pat,rep,"""
=== Something here ===
""")))
print(repr(re.sub(pat,rep,"""===
Something here
===""")))
```

Outputs

```
>>> 
'<h2> Something here </h2>'
'<h2>Something here</h2>'
```

I copied and pasted text from Scite set up like you:

[image]

---

For multline I would recommend this:

```
import re
patSearch = r'\n?===\n?[a-zA-Z\s]*?\n?==='
patReplace = r'\n?(===)\n?([a-zA-Z\s]*?)\n?(===)\n?\n?'
replacement  = r'<h2>\2</h2>'
```

With a string `t`:

```
t="""===Something here===

Lorem ipsum lala.  

===
Something here
===

Loreum ipsum lala."""
```

The following

```
matches = re.findall(patSearch,t) #get all the === ... === style string
for match in matches:
    print re.sub(patReplace,replacement,match) #do replacement in each one
```

Would produce

```
>>> 
<h2>Something here</h2>
<h2>Something here</h2>
```

Comment: i tried this suggestion in the context i am working with and it didn't perform substitution on multiline instance. i amended post above to show what i tried.

Comment: @user1063287 Okay, I've updated it to reflect the multiline nature of your file

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this solution:

```
import re
s = """===Something here===

Lorem ipsum lala.  

===
Something here
===

Loreum ipsum lala.  """
result = re.sub(r"===(.*?)===", r"<h2>\1</h2>", s, flags=re.DOTALL)
print result
```

Some explanations:

- `.*?` matches any character in "non greedy" mode: matches as little data as possible. This is to avoid that `===First=== lalala ===Second===` is substituted by `<h2>First=== lalala ===Second</h2>`
- `flags=re.DOTALL` means that `.` matches *any* char, including newlines

Note that you need to apply sub() to the entire file, not line by line

Answer (score 1):

Compile the regular expression using flag `re.DOTALL`: this will make the character `.` match newline too. The `$` should be used to force the ending pattern. You need not use `\s` in Blender's solution anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add the whitespace in between the capturing groups:

```
re.sub(r"(===)\s*([a-zA-Z\s]*?)\s*(===)", r"<h2>\2</h2>", line)
```

You could also use a non-greedy capturing group:

```
re.sub(r"(===)\s*(.*?)\s*(===)", r"<h2>\2</h2>", line)
```

Comment: i tried the suggestion of adding `\s*` between groups and it caused the function it is within not to work (no errors, it just didn't output specified information).  the second suggestion caused the same behaviour. i have updated the above post with more information.

Answer (score 0):

User1063287, if you're still having issues I recommend the solution posted by Zac. I was having similar issues to yours, and the 're.DOTALL' flag was the trick that allowed my replacement to occur as I intended. My problem also involved accessing text from a .txt file. Here's a suggestion for how to code your specific issue, based on what worked for me (note that I saved output to a new .txt)

```
import re
with open('output.txt', "w") as o:
    with open('input', 'r') as i:
        line = i.read()
        line = re.sub(r"===.*?===", r"<h2>\2</h2>", line, flags=re.DOTALL)      
    o.write(line)
```

The with statements will allow your input and output files to close when the loop completes, and the i.read() command allows the entire file to be read at once (rather than accessed line-by-line). I don't see why you could not put this code into a def function, but I haven't tried it to be sure.

Good luck!